# Javascript load Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, load

I just wanted to ask how do you ensure that element details (e.g position in viewport, getBoundingClientRect) are correct when loading your page for the first time. Currently I have a problem with a normal div-element. It is displayed right after an image which i get with a fetch statement. I used the load-event on window and after the Page is loaded I get the information of the position of the div-element. Unfortunately the load-fires before the Image is loaded and that means the position details are wrong.
How and when do you use the load Event? And what Else can i do to ensure i receive the right position details.

Html
`<div class="wrapperImg"></div> <div class="position"></div>`

Js
`window.addEventListener("load",()=>{console.log(document.querySelector(".position").getBoundingClientRect());}`

Many thanks
Regards
Kat

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to call the `getBoundingClientRect()` after the image has loaded, which means when your fetch call has resolved (as it is executed asynchronously).

To keep in mind: The load event does not include asnyc fetched resources (as those are handled dynamically). For more info on the load event [see the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea how to solve this issue? The fetch statement is in another script file and the Image element will be issued through js it doesn't exist when the second js file executes.

Comment: Do you know or have control over the image size (width and height)? If yes you could use a placeholder image. If you have control over the second script you could use a custom event to inform your first script about the image).

Comment: I found a solution. Not a good one but it works. I added the Event listener in the first script right after i created the Image and wrapped my second script in a function which starts when the Event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`'load'` event listener can also be applied on images like this:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = "img.jpg";
img.onload = function () {
   alert("image is loaded");
}
```

Also you can get `getBoundingClientRect()` properties after the fetch:

```js
fetch('image.png').then(i => {
  //get size
})
```

Comment: you should use an `addEventListener` to append the event. The usage of `onload` is "outdated" because it overwrites other events.

Comment: `onload` indeed overwrites other events, but I don't really think it's necessary to make it longer in this case.

Comment: Well the OP already use it. On the other side you do not know if the OP already uses an onload event. It is always better to code with redundancy and availability in mind as otherwise you create a potentially new issue.